# Generics when trying to implement interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Problem: I have many file types that I want to parse. Each one parses a file  and returns a result (`List<>`)  of objects. I want to have just one `IFileParser` interface and specify the parser type and return set at time of calling `Parse`

I have an interface like this

```
public interface IFileParser
{
    TResponse Parse<TFileParserType,TResponse>(string file);
}
```

being injected into a service like this

```
private readonly IFileParser _fileParser;
 public CarService(IFileParser fileParser)

        {
            _fileParser = fileParser;

        }
```

being used

```
var cardatas = _fileParser.Parse<CarFileParser, List<CarData>>("car.txt");
  var bikedatas = _fileParser.Parse<BikeFileParser, List<BikeData>>("bike.txt");
```

implementation - this part does not work...why?
error returned is

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CarData>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TResponse>'

---

```
 public class CarFileParser : IFileParser
    {
        public List<CarData> Parse(string filePath)
        {
            return new List<CarData>() //does not work...why??
        }


        public TResponse Parse<TType, TResponse>(string file)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); 
            //this is what it should be 
            //but how do I return a List<CarData> 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the use of TType in the code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that is the 'file parser type'

Comment: how is `CarData` related to `ClearingHouseSuperannuationData` ? why do you try to return `return new List<CarData>()` is the return type is designated as `List<ClearingHouseSuperannuationData>` ?

Comment: Can you add code for CarData and ClearingHouseSuperannuationData... Are those type compatible?

Comment: Seems like an array contravariance problem...

Comment: Sorry. They are both meant to be cardata. I simplified example

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why is the generic on the method, and not on the type? Your interface says that the method *must* be generic, which means that an implementing method *must* be able to return *anything*. Since it can and must return *anything that the caller requires* you cannot *force* it to return a particular type. I think you don't understand what generic methods are; can you explain what you think a generic method is for?

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious that I do not have a great understanding of genetics but maybe you don't have to be so condescending about it. I've stated my problem and what I am trying to do. Perhaps if you spared the lecture and actually show me where I am going wrong I might learn something.

Comment: Generics even. Typing on my phone. Lol

Answer (score 0):

Not claiming this to be the Answer. Does this help:

```
public interface IFileParser<TResponse>
    {
        TResponse Parse(string file);
    }

    public class CarFileParser : IFileParser<List<CarData>>
    {
        public List<CarData> Parse(string file)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be good if you could share the thoughts behind this code. Why is this supposed to help opposed to the code version of OP ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, return type should match with return value:

```
    public List<CarData> Parse(string filePath)
    {
        return new List<CarData>() //Will work..
    }
```

while doing the type conversion, a list cannot be convert to class. If you want this, create a property in class.

```
    var cardatas = _fileParser.Parse<CarFileParserList, List<CarData>>("car.txt");

    class CarFileParser
    {
     public List<CarFile> CarFileParserList{get;set;}
    }

    public class CarFile
    {
     //create property here
    }
```

then you can use this code:

```
     var cardatas = _fileParser.Parse<List<CarFile>, List<CarData>>("car.txt");
     var carFileParser= new CarFileParser();
     carFileParser.CarFileParserList=cardatas;
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid instantiating a new parser in the code so that code is not what I am trying to do. I do not want to create a new CarFile Parser in the code. I am injecting it using IOC

Answer (score 0):

If it always returns a list, maybe try

```
 List<TResponse> Parse<TFileParserType, TResponse>(string file);
```

and then

```
 List<CarData> cardatas = _fileParser.Parse<CarFileParser, CarData>("car.txt");
```

(or possibly `ICollection` / `IEnumerable`)

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would prefer to implement the type / interface like this. Not sure if this works with your injection.

```
// Put the type of data on the interface / type
public interface IFileParser<TData>
{
    IEnumerable<TData> Parse(string file);
}

// Implement the interface
public class CarParser : IFileParser<CarData>
{
    ...
}

// The method where to inject the implementation:
public IEnumerable<TData> Parse<TData>(IFileParser<TData> parser, string file)
{
    return parser.Parse(file);
}

// The implementations would have to be injected here:
private readonly IFileParser<CarData> _carFileParser;
private readonly IFileParser<BikeData> _bikeFileParser;

var carData = Parse(_carFileParser, file);
var bikeData = Parse(_bikeFileParser, file);
```

Comment: thanks @marsze the only problem I see is the instantiation of the new CarfileParser instance. I want to inject it into the service as an interface. For the time being I have gone with 2 separate interfaces (car and bike) of a fileParser. Not a great solution

Comment: I changed my answer. You cannot have only *one* `_fileParser` field, if you need more than one implementation.

Comment: @kurasa No feedback!?

Comment: sorry..have been busy...I ended up going with 3 different interfaces as I could not get it to work and I had to deliver it..your answer is exactly what I had to start with but was unable to use a single interface with generics to create it...I suspect it is something simple on my end I am missing..thanks for your help